# scrollHeight property only updates when changed content is taller

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm observing strange behaviour with scrollHeight (or perhaps I misunderstand exactly how/when it gets updated). I noticed that when replacing content inside an "overflow:hidden" element and attempting to explicitly set its height via the scrollHeight property (so I can animate with CSS) it only adjusts to the correct height when the replaced content is **taller** than before. Replacing the contents with shorter (or less) content, the scrollHeight property of the element stays at the larger value. I've outlined it in a simple test below in jQuery. I'm observing this in Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

Why is this happening?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $cart = $('#cart')
    $cart.css('height', $cart.prop('scrollHeight'))
})
```

Comment: Would it not be possible for a pure css solution?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Javascript height calculation is necessary for "overflow:hidden" elements that need to be toggled for animation. If I scrap the animation, of course, I just switch CSS height between 0 and auto but that looks pants!